# To pass to object data pug in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

The existing code was written as MySQL query and I am now working on converting it to Mongoose query.

I need to get five data sorted by the most recent subscription year from the main page.

The existing code brought this result value into an array. And data was delivered through pug view, and Mongoose seems to bring the result value of Object. In this case, I wonder how to deliver the data through Pug view.

I checked importing data from the terminal to the console.log, but an error called 'Error `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set heads after they are sent to the client` occurs and no data is passed to the pug. I wonder why this problem occurs.

**[MySQL Query]**

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  // Main page Profile Data Process
  db.query(`SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY registerDate DESC LIMIT 5`, function (
    error,
    data
  ) {
    // Log Error
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    res.render("main", {
      dataarray: data,
      _user: req.user,
      url: url
    });
  });
});
```

**[Mongoose Query]**

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  let dataarray = [];
  let userData = db.collection("user").find().limit(5).sort({
    "created_at": -1
});
  userData.each(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      if (doc != null) {
        dataarray.push(doc)
      }
    }
    // console.log(dataarray.login)
    console.log(dataarray);
    res.render("main", {
      dataarray,
      _user: req.user
    })
  });
});
```

**[pug file]**

```
each profile in dataarray
        .col-lg-4
          img.rounded-circle(src=`${profile.avatar_url}` alt='Generic placeholder image' width='140' height='140')
          h2=`${profile.login}`
          p=`${profile.bio}`
          p
            a.btn.btn-secondary(href=`/${profile.login}` role='button') View details &raquo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the request in multiple chunks, node/express uses one request and one response.

> Cannot set heads after they are sent to the client

Is the error that happens when the res.render is called the second time.  At this point, the one request has already left the node/express process and this is tell you that you're trying to violate the one request/one response paradigm.

This is the part of your code where you can see why this happens.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  let dataarray = [];
  let userData = db.collection("user").find().limit(5).sort({
    "created_at": -1
});
  userData.each(function (err, doc) {
```

This part of your code will try to send a response for each item in your resultset.

Something like this will work properly (I didn't test it):

```
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {

  db.collection("user").find().limit(5).sort({ "created_at": -1 }, function(err, userData){

    res.render("main", {
      dataarray: userData,
      _user: req.user
    })

  });

});
```

In other words, only one res.render is required and pass the entire result set into that.